# SQL ORDER BY with exceptions

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-order-by, rank

I would like to sort (the result of the sub select) by 3 columns (Priority, ExpectedDate, CreateDate) but for a few row sort should work in different way.
It is hard to describe in words so I prepared a picture:

[image]

Column **Rank** in **Before** table is right now:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Priority DESC, ExpectedDate DESC, CreateDate ASC) AS [Rank],
```

As you can see **ShouldBeAfter** column indicates the **ID**, after which this row should always appear, regardless of the sort.

How to write a query in order to achieve a state of **After**?

**EDIT 1:**
Sample data:

```
DECLARE @Queue TABLE 
(
    [ChildID] INT,
    [ParentID] INT,
    [No] INT,
    [Change] INT,
    [Priority] INT,
    [ExpectedDate] DATETIME,
    [CreateDate] DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO @Queue VALUES (242,   0, 0, 0,  3, '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000', '2015-11-27 15:08:40.677')
INSERT INTO @Queue VALUES (243, 274, 0, 0,  3, '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000', '2015-11-27 15:22:46.350')
INSERT INTO @Queue VALUES (244,   0, 0, 0,  3, '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000', '2015-11-27 15:29:52.010')
INSERT INTO @Queue VALUES (259,   0, 0, 0,  3, '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000', '2015-11-30 15:54:48.710')
INSERT INTO @Queue VALUES (261,   0, 0, 0,  4, '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000', '2015-12-01 11:07:32.357')
INSERT INTO @Queue VALUES (263,   0, 0, 0,  5, '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000', '2015-12-02 12:07:01.980')
INSERT INTO @Queue VALUES (264,   0, 0, 0,  2, '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000', '2015-12-03 14:58:19.717')
INSERT INTO @Queue VALUES (266,   0, 0, 0,  3, '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000', '2015-12-08 09:55:06.277')
INSERT INTO @Queue VALUES (269,   0, 0, 0,  3, '2015-12-16 00:00:00.000', '2015-12-08 17:53:24.820')
INSERT INTO @Queue VALUES (270,   0, 0, 0,  3, '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000', '2015-12-09 15:50:37.970')
INSERT INTO @Queue VALUES (272,   0, 0, 0,  3, '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000', '2015-12-11 12:06:19.253')
INSERT INTO @Queue VALUES (273, 242, 0, 0,  3, '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000', '2015-12-11 12:08:20.010')
INSERT INTO @Queue VALUES (274,   0, 0, 0,  2, '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000', '2015-12-11 12:09:00.200')
INSERT INTO @Queue VALUES (275,   0, 0, 0,  3, '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000', '2015-12-11 12:14:50.110')
INSERT INTO @Queue VALUES (276,   0, 0, 0,  3, '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000', '2015-12-11 12:17:49.220')
INSERT INTO @Queue VALUES (277,   0, 0, 0,  3, '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000', '2015-12-11 12:24:28.823')
INSERT INTO @Queue VALUES (278,   0, 0, 0,  5, '2015-12-10 00:00:00.000', '2015-12-11 12:27:53.803')
INSERT INTO @Queue VALUES (279,   0, 0, 0,  3, '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000', '2015-12-11 12:32:14.397')
INSERT INTO @Queue VALUES (280,   0, 0, 0,  2, '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000', '2015-12-11 13:56:06.080')
INSERT INTO @Queue VALUES (281,   0, 0, 0,  2, '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000', '2015-12-15 10:16:35.057')
INSERT INTO @Queue VALUES (282, 276, 0, 0,  3, '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000', '2015-12-15 10:18:50.180')
INSERT INTO @Queue VALUES (284,   0, 0, 0,  3, '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000', '2015-12-15 11:33:33.553')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in two-step process using CTEs:

```
;WITH InitialRank AS (
SELECT *,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Priority DESC, 
                                  ExpectedDate DESC, 
                                  CreateDate ASC) AS [Rank]
FROM Queue
), FinalRank AS (
SELECT t1.ID, t1.ShouldBeAfter, t1.No, t1.Change,
       t1.Priority, t1.ExpectedDate, t1.CreateDate,
       COALESCE(CAST(t2.Rank AS DECIMAL(4,1)) + 0.5, t1.Rank) AS Rank
FROM InitialRank AS t1
LEFT JOIN InitialRank AS t2 
ON t1.ShouldBeAfter <> 0 AND t1.ShouldBeAfter = t2.ID
)
SELECT ID, ShouldBeAfter, No, Change,
       Priority, ExpectedDate, CreateDate,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Rank) AS Rank
FROM FinalRank
ORDER BY Rank
```

- The first step calculates the *'initial'* rank as defined by the 3 columns `(Priority, ExpectedDate, CreateDate)`.
- Second step alters the rank of all rows having a non-zero `ShouldBeAfter` value associated with them: the new value of the rank is the rank of 'comes before' row plus `0.5`, so that the row will be ordered *right after* the 'comes before' row.

*Note*: The above will work as long as there are only *single-level* dependencies.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b0be8/7)

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do the same without explicit join:

```
SELECT *,
  MIN(CASE WHEN ShouldBeAfter = 0 THEN PreRank END)
    OVER(PARTITION BY CASE WHEN ShouldBeAfter = 0 THEN ID ELSE ShouldBeAfter END) AS [Rank]
FROM (
  SELECT *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Priority DESC, ExpectedDate DESC, CreateDate ASC) AS [PreRank]
  FROM Queue
)A
ORDER BY [Rank], ShouldBeAfter
```

[Demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b0be8/12/0)

Comment: In the result, you can see a doubling rank: 5, 14, 20. The final result should be renumbered.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a pain, because you need an additional join:

```
select t.*
from t left join
     t2
     on t.id = t2.shouldbeafter
order by coalesce(t2.shouldbeafter, t.id),
         t.shouldbeafter, t.id;
```

Note: this works for one level, but won't work for multiple levels.

Comment: It is not working. I added the sample data (check EDIT 1).